# In which cases a tcp receiver receives a valid syn segment but still no syn ack?

Tags: networking, tcp

In which cases, a TCP receiver receives a valid SYN segment but still WONT send a SYN-ACK segment in response?

Answer (score 1):

This is platform-dependnt. In Unix, if the backlog queue is full, incoming SYNs are dropped. In other platforms this condition causes an RST.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is low on memory, a received SYN packet can be dropped inside the system. The other case is if the server is slow in processing its backlog queue, then it might reach a high water mark and any new recv SYN will be dropped. The backlog queue depth is set via the second argument in the listen() call in linux. The behavior of the backlog argument on TCP sockets changed with Linux 2.2. Now it specifies the queue length for completely established sockets waiting to be accepted, instead of the number of incomplete connection requests. The maximum length of the queue for incomplete sockets can be set using /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog. The default is 128 on linux. A low value can slow down a server response time under load.

Comment: The default is more like 500 these days. Windows doesn't drop the SYN in this circumstance, it issues an RST.